# I can't paint the whole model in texture paint mode

Tags: texturing, uv, image, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I have a problem in texture paint mode. If I unwrap the model, I can't paint the entire mesh. It remains entirely white. More details in this picture.

[image: Cannot apply the paint]

If you can answer too why is it stay black :/ but the properly uv texture changing transparent white.

Answer (score 1):

If it stays 'full white' then quite possible you don't have an image texture assigned to the UVs yet - in the Tool Bar, check for a warning to 'add paint slot below' as in the attached picture.[image: add image texture]

Comment: Thanks for answer Jones :). it's can cause the error too, but i had uv map and i could paint it. My problem was that if you union two object and if you had material one of them you have too assign the object material what you add later to the object or make a new material but i didnt know this :/. Thanks a lot Jones for answering!!